# Can i get yesterday deleted file?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Yesterday worked on the project without any problem till last working minute. today a file is missing. Please any one can suggest if it possible to recover.Thank you in advance.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: That depends but my piece of advice please make it a habit of using Version control like Git.

Comment: use github or bitbucket.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta sir, Clean-Rebuild will not help for that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check **Local History**

Try right click on CLASS or XML file and check **`Local History -> Show History`**

If history is available, you can riright-clickhe history entry and click revert.

**Note**

For good approach, You should use **`github`** or **`bitbucket`**.

Comment: to right click on class . class has to be there . if its deleted than

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No, We check local history previous also

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya If we are not cleaning temp files from our system, it will show you local history of code. For me its showing from last month.

Comment: Well elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, if it suits you (apart from android studio).

At Your file location please check with file recovery software. If it is deleted than **recovery software** like [this](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) can recover it for you. Just run them at that location.